# Why is Wiener process a homogenous but not a stationary stochastic process?

Tags: classical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I found the claim that wiener process is an example of a stochastic process which is homogeneous but not stationary in the book 'The Theory of Open Quantum Systems' by Breuer and Petruccione. (Section 1.4.1 The Chapman-Kolmogorov equation, near equation 1.62).

Let us first do the basic definition-

**Stationary stochastic process**: a stochastic process for which
$$
p_m(x_m,t_m+T;...;x_1,t_1+T)=p_m(x_m,t_m;...;x_1,t_1) \tag{1}
$$
for all $T$.

Intuitively, this means that the statistical probability for a certain path to be chosen by the system does not change over time.

**Homogeneous stochastic process**: Process for which the conditional transition probability of transition happening from $x_1$,$t_1$ to $x_n$,$t_n$, represented as $T(x_n,t_n|x_1,t_1)$, has the property-
$$
T(x_n,t_n+T|x_1,t_1+T)=T(x_n,t_n|x_1,t_1)\tag{2}
$$

There is similarity between equations (1) and (2). But the difference is apparent from the definition of $T(x_n,t_n|x_1,t_1)$.
$$
T(x_n,t_n|x_1,t_1)={\sum _{x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1}} p_n(x_n,t_n;...;x_2,t_2|x_1,t_1)} \tag{3}
$$

**The Question:**
As I understand it, Wiener process is a continuous time limit of random walk. The path the system takes is decided by a coin toss. The paths appear to obey eqn (1), and hence Wiener process should be a stationary AND homogeneous stochastic process.

The textbook claims that it is homogeneous, but not stationary. Why?

Comment: Eq. 1 is already violated for m=1 which is immediate from the density. Intuitively, if an additional time T is allowed to pass, the process has the chance to move further away from where it started.

Comment: @Nephente Thanks for the comment. I think I misunderstood what $P(x_n,t_n;...;x_1;t_1)$ means. I was thinking of it (incorrectly) like $P(x_n,t_n;...;x_2,t_2|x_1,t_1)$. That is, the probability that the system will follow the given path given that it already occupies the initial state. This incorrect interpretation also makes eqn (3) invalid. Will edit it. So, basically, this answers my question. Probability distribution of a stationary process remains 'stationary' through time. Random walk disperses with variance $\sqrt{T}$. Random walk is not stationary.